# Chrome extension failing to load because browser canceling requests

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension that uses the "webRequest" permissions in the background script to listen for matching URLs, that then loads the content script using "chrome.tabs.executeScript()".  This pattern seems to work most of the time, however, I stumbled on a website that is canceling asset requests made to the extension and is causing a failure to load.

The request for assets is made in the "content.js" script using chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html").  This is the request that is being canceled.

### How to install Chrome Extension:

1. I created a github repo for this example https://github.com/dasimandl/stackoverflow-chrome-extension
2. clone github repo and then run "npm install"
3. In Chrome browser, goto chrome://extensions
4. Make sure that developer mode is enabled (toggle in top right corner)
5. Click "load unpacked" (top left corner), point to the location of "dist" directory

### How to reproduce issue:

1. (SUCCESS CASE) visit any website https://stackoverflow.com - Chrome extension will load an iframe that has "Hello World" text.

   - check dev-tools for "index.html" and you will see 200 response code
2. (FAIL CASE) visit https://www.td.com/us/en/personal-banking/ - **iframe will load, but index.html asset will fail**

   - check dev-tools for "index.html" notice that the request is "canceled"

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "myExtension",
  "short_name": "myExtension",
  "version": "4.1.2",
  "description": "myExtension",
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*", 
    "tabs", 
    "webRequest",
    "storage"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "myExtension"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["backgroundPage.js"]
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; object-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; ",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["index.html"]
}
```

**backgroundPage.js**

```
const PATTERNS = ['https://*/*'];

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
    saveResponse,
    {
        urls: [...PATTERNS]
    },
    ['responseHeaders']
);

function saveResponse(responseDetails) {
    console.log('saveResponse -> responseDetails', responseDetails);
    const { tabId } = responseDetails;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        file: 'content.js'
    });
}
```

**content.js**

```
/* global chrome */
(function() {
  if (!document.getElementById("myExtensionIframe")) {
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var myExtensionContainer = document.createElement("div");
    iframe.name = iframe.id = "myExtensionIframe";
    myExtensionContainer.id = "myExtensionContainer";
    iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");

    myExtensionContainer.style.height = "100%";
    myExtensionContainer.style.width = "338px";
    myExtensionContainer.style.position = "fixed";
    myExtensionContainer.style.display = "inline";
    myExtensionContainer.style.opacity = "1";
    myExtensionContainer.style.margin = "0px";
    myExtensionContainer.style.padding = "0px";
    myExtensionContainer.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    myExtensionContainer.style.top = "0px";
    myExtensionContainer.style.right = "0px";
    myExtensionContainer.textAlign = "left";
    myExtensionContainer.border = "solid 1px #666666";
    myExtensionContainer.style["-webkit-box-shadow"] = "0px 0px 15px black";
    myExtensionContainer.style.overflow = "hidden";
    myExtensionContainer.style.zIndex = 2147483645;

    //style iframe elements
    iframe.style.display = "block";
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.style.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.style.margin = 0;
    iframe.style.resize = "none";

    // add to body
    if (!document.getElementById("iframe")) {
      myExtensionContainer.appendChild(iframe);
      document.body.appendChild(myExtensionContainer);
      console.log('appending iframe to body')
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Already loaded ******");
  }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Extension</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</body>

</html>
```